# Bootstrap InputFile Initial Preview Shows image as original size

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Krajee Bootstrap FileInput. I'm using initialPreview tag and have below issues:

1. Initial image is shown in original image size not the thumbnail size
2. Cannot delete the initial image.
3. I have use `overwriteInitial` and `autoReplace`, but when I add a new image, the initial is still there. I expect it overwrite the initial image but it doesn't

This is my script:

```
<script>
    $("#file-1").fileinput({
        initialPreview: [
            "<img src='/img/Tulips.jpg' class='file-preview-image' title='Desert'>"
        ],
        uploadUrl: "@Url.Action("upload","Home")", 
        uploadAsync: true,
        allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif'],
        maxFilesNum: 1,
        allowedFileTypes: ['image'],
        overwriteInitial: true,
        autoReplace: true,
        showUpload: true,
        showCaption: true,
        showUploadedThumbs: true,
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe set size in width in img tag?

```
<script>
$("#file-1").fileinput({
    initialPreview: [
        "<img src='/img/Tulips.jpg' class='file-preview-image' title='Desert' width='120' >"
    ],
    uploadUrl: "@Url.Action("upload","Home")", 
    uploadAsync: true,
    allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif'],
    maxFilesNum: 1,
    allowedFileTypes: ['image'],
    overwriteInitial: true,
    autoReplace: true,
    showUpload: true,
    showCaption: true,
    showUploadedThumbs: true,
});
```

Comment: Thanks for late answer!. I'm out of that project but will remind your solution if I needed to use that widget in future.